# Is an ultra-net a subnet of all it's subnets?

Tags: general-topology, filters, nets

Let $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ be a net on a set $X$ and the set
$$\{\{x_d\mid d\ge p\}\mid p\in D \}$$
be a base for an ultrafilter on $X$.

Let $(x_{d'})_{d'\in D'}$ be a subnet of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$. Is $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ a subnet of $(x_{d'})_{d'\in D'}$?

Comment: Do we really need a [nets] tag?

Comment: I know they are not. But I am trying to raise the question, do we *really* need such tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ultranet (or universal net) has no proper subnets, so the answer is *yes*; see Lemma $13.3$ of [this PDF](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf) by Saitulaa Naranong. (Note that the implication in the displayed line of Definition $10.2$ is backwards: $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ should be interchanged.)